# Maven XML files, 2 different source directories with files of same name

Tags: xml, maven

I have an Maven XML that is used to create 1 tar file but with multiple source directories.  It's all working except that 2 of the source directories have a file with the same name, 2 versions.  How do i control which version it picks?  Can i do it by the order of the source in the xml file?  In the example, the directory abc and abcd have the a file with the same name.  will it pick the one from abc since it's first or abcd since it's last or random?

```
    <fileSet>
        <directory>assembly/abc/custom</directory>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/.gitattributes</exclude>
        </excludes>
        <outputDirectory>custom</outputDirectory>
    </fileSet>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>assembly/abcd/custom</directory>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/.gitattributes</exclude>
        </excludes>
        <outputDirectory>custom</outputDirectory>
    </fileSet>
```

Comment: What do you mean by multiple source directories? Usually you have only `src/main/java` and for tests  `src/test/java`? What kind of problem are  you trying to solve?

Comment: It's not java code.  It's a unix script.  In the above example, there is 1 version in the directory assembly/abc/custom and another in assemply/abcd/custom.   It appears it's taking the version in abcd.  I want it to use the version in abc.  I inherited this so changes that i can make are limited.

Comment: The problem i'm trying to solve is i want to make sure it's going to use the version in abc directory consistenly.

Comment: If you have the same file you should only include that file not both cause than the result is based on the order within the pom.xml file... Apart from that I would question what kind of script (bash?) you need within a jar file?